# Which states are supported by marketplace.api.healthcare.gov

Tags: healthcare-finder-api

I am using https://marketplace.api.healthcare.gov/api/v1/plans/search?

```
  "place": {
      "countyfips": '06085',
      "state":'CA',
      "zipcode":'95129'    
}
```

I am getting:

{"code":"1003","status":"400","message":"state is not a valid marketplace state","error":"state is not a valid marketplace state"}

Answer (score 0):

Only states on the federal exchange are available through that api. All states on this state-based exchange list would not be available: https://www.cms.gov/CCIIO/Resources/Fact-Sheets-and-FAQs/state-marketplaces